# HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I'm trying to use `HtmlAgilityPack` to get any element has `green`.

Thanks for the help.

Sample HTML:

```
<span id="CPH_Main_ucArbitrage_headerTaInfData" class=" green ">0.46%</span>
```

The code I've used:

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument docHtml = new HtmlWeb().Load("https://www.globes.co.il/portal/arbitrage/");
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();

HtmlNode node = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//span[@id='CPH_Main_ucArbitrage_headerTaInfData']");

string value = (node == null) ? "Error, id not found": node.InnerHtml;
MessageBox.Show(value);
```

Comment: What is your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument docHtml = new HtmlWeb().Load("https://www.globes.co.il/portal/arbitrage/");

HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
```

You have a `docHtml` variable which has already loaded `https://www.globes.co.il` HTML, then, you again defined a new `doc` variable which has initialized an empty `HtmlDocument`.

In this part of your code:

```
HtmlNode node = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode
```

You are referencing `doc` variable which is empty! and that's why you face the error. You have to use `docHtml`.

```
HtmlNode node = docHtml.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode
```

Comment: Ali Bahrami  - Thanks a lot it helped,  how do I get the  class=" green "     (green-red)       <span id="CPH_Main_ucArbitrage_headerTaInfData" class=" green ">0.46%</span>